# Subscribing to Web Application Events from WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, events

I have a simple web application that allows users to upload a file to the server and store the data in the Database.

There will be a decoupled service (probably WCF) which needs to act upon the data, but i am not sure what the best mechanism is to alert the service?  Is it a good idea for the WCF service to poll the database every few minutes to check for new data?  Or should i be looking at other patterns (?) to better accomplish this task? using Events perhaps?

I have not done anything like this before so looking for some guidance to start off with.

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem with calling the WCF service at the end of upload from ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to call the service from the web application in the same code that performs the upload? Typically, an application calls a service, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Polling from client side is an option. Or you can have a non duplex service for file upload and have a duplex service for callback on the progress of the upload.
Also Take a look this [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF_FileTransfer_Progress.aspx) which uses non duplex channels to track file upload and download.